# Substring Replace Vector

Tags: c++, vector, replace, substring

*This is a minimal code sample*

I'm trying to create an array of substrings to find so I can replace them with a single word. In this case I'm changing common greetings into a simple 'hi'.

The problem is that when I run the code I'm getting an error.

*error: no matching function to call to 'std::vector >::push_back(const char [4], const char [4], const char [3])'*

If someone could help me understand why this error is occurring and suggest a solution that would be perfect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

    vector<string> hiWord;
    hiWord.push_back("hey", "sup", "yo");
    for (const auto& word : hiWord){
    while (true) {
     index = r.find(word);
     if (index == string::npos)
        break;
     r.replace(index, word.size(), "hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is very hard to read, please format it.

Comment: Specify the question so that it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: is this an excercise? or a minimal (code) sample? as is, there could be many answers to this question, and none makes a lot of sense. for example, counting the number of words in a string and returning this many times "hi " would also work for your example.

Comment: It is a minimal code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by creating a vector of the strings you want to search for and replace:

```
vector<string> searchWords = {"hey", "hello", "sup"};
```

Then use a loop to run the code you already wrote, e.g.

```
for (const auto& word : searchWords) {
  while (true) {
     index = r.find(word);
     if (index == string::npos)
        break;
     r.replace(index, word.size(), "hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of the vector isn't working. It gives me the error "error: in C++98 'seachWords' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'" Do you have any reason why?

Comment: Yeah, the way I wrote it uses C++11 syntax.  If your compiler supports C++11, you should set it up to use that.  Otherwise you can break out that line into a separate declaration and calls to `vector::push_back` like this: 
`vector<string> searchWords;`
`searchWords.push_back("hey");`
etc...

Comment: The ranged-for loop in my answer is also a C++11 construct, so you might have to convert that to the old style as well.

Comment: Alright, I've switched the code but it's now giving me a new error, which is 'error: no matching function to call'.

Comment: Can you post the new code as an edit to your original post?

Comment: You need to call `push_back` separately for each word.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. Now I have a new error. This one is "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'word' with no type [-fpermissive]". This is just perfect, eh?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating your own replace functions

```
void replace(std::string &str, const std::string &token, const std::string &newToken)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    while((index = r.find(token, index)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        r.replace(index, token.length(), newToken);
    }
}

//You can overload this function to take a vector, Array or whathever you like
void replace(std::string &str, const std::vector<std::string> &tokens, const std::string &newToken)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
    {
        replace(str, tokens[i], newToken);
    }
}

//And you can call it like this
string r("hey hello sup");

replace(r, "hey", "hi");
replace(r, {"hello", "sup"}, "hi");
```

Comment: This is a good idea but and may work in another instance but the variable *r* cannot be replaced like in your code. It still holds other information that can't be lost.

Comment: @PlayerCoder so you Need to make your question more clear. I actually don't get what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: This is true, sorry. It's just that I was told to give the information that was relevant and I thought everything I put in my question was the only things that were.